# Problem to open REPL using Xamarin Test Cloud

Tags: c#, xamarin, testing, xamarin-test-cloud

I'm beginner in Xamarin Test Cloud and I want to write tests for Xamarin Test Cloud.

I have Xamarin UITests in my solution and I tried to launch REPL, but UITest REPL window didn't open.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Xamarin.UITest;
using Xamarin.UITest.Android;
using Xamarin.UITest.Queries;

namespace MurakamiKiev.UITests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Tests
    {
        AndroidApp app;

        [SetUp]
        public void BeforeEachTest ()
        {
            app = ConfigureApp.Android.StartApp ();
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestLaunch ()
        {
            app.Repl();
        }
    }
}
```

Where is the error?

Also, what I need to write to launch specified activity?

Comment: No one don't know answer???

Comment: Your approach matches this doc: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/working-with/repl/#Starting_the_REPL

Therefore, the problem is likely somewhere else in your code. Have you followed the steps in this guide to setup the UITest project and reference it to your Android app? https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/adding-uitest/

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the application source code in the same solution then you'll need to specify the prebuilt app by pointing to it via a full path.

```
[SetUp]
    public void BeforeEachTest ()
    {
        app = ConfigureApp.Android.ApkFile("<path-as-string>").StartApp ();
    }
```